# Shemona Ve'arba'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred forty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly 148 years ago today (December 17, 1862), General Ulysses S Grant issued  [General Order No. 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Order_No._11_%281862%29) expelling all Jews out of his military district.

Answer (score 2):

148 were the years of *Nachor*. Fits the beat. Source: end of *Noach*.

Answer (score -2):

Kemach   =   148